# Aurigma 7, How to hide checkAll checkbox in the folderpane header

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, aurigma

Is there a way to hide checkAll checkbox in the aurigma uploader ver 7 (folder pane header)

i tried this way, but it doesn't take any effects

> iu.addParam("ButtonCheckAllText", "");
>   iu.addParam("ButtonUncheckAllText", "");

FYI

i use Ruby on Rails, and call the aurigma with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way unfortunately.

And it looks like you are using scripts from earlier version, in Uploader 7 javascript was completely changed.